# Exporting a pdf - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, http-status-code-404, angular-ui-bootstrap, pdfmake

I am getting a 404 error when I try to export tablles and a ui-grid as a pdf using pdfmake. It works perfectly in Firefox, but not with Chrome

I am getting this msg twice

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

and then it points to both

```
ui-bootstrap-2.4.0.min.js
```

and

```
:7001/favicon.ico
```

I am using a localhost to run the application.

My current version is 57.0.2987.133

ui-bootstrap is set in the js folder with all the other files.

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to turn off add blocker and it worked